# Windows & died om PC. I want to replace it but I use TablEdit. Any advice?

Tags: music

So my son tells me I should join the 20th century.

I would like to run Linux but I use a music editing program called TablEdit, and have a load of music already stored in this format which I am not willing / too idle to replace. Is there a version of Linux that allows this, or is there a music editor ( for music manuscript) which runs or imports .tab files?